# How much expensive is JWT decrypt

Tags: api, jwt, json-web-token

I am using JWT for API authentication.
I am just curious to know how much expensive is to decrypt the JWT each time when a request arrives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the algorithm(s) used.

(Note that JWT supports *signing* as well as *encryption* - signed JWTs are the more common use case; my answer is general.)

The symmetric key algorithms (AES, HMAC) are the least expensive (very fast).
For public key algorithms, RSA-based algorithms are the most expensive, and elliptic curve algorithms (ECDH for key encryption, ECDSA for signing) are less computationally expensive but still more expensive than symmetric algorithms.

Comment: I am using RS256 algorithm. So is there any problem with the usual processing since it is expensive? I am using Node.js as server. so is there any performance lag?

Comment: Well, that depends on how many requests per second versus your hardware and the software implementation of RS256.  In general, the ECC and HMAC algorithms are faster (per my answer).

Comment: Yes, and the choice between ECC (public key) or HMAC (shared secret) will largely depend on your use case (a topic for another question).